# How to debug dm-verity block corruption issue in Android

Tags: android, linux-kernel

dm-verity is complaining of a dm-verity data corrupted.
Is there any pointers or idea how we can debug such filesystem corruption issues.

Answer (score 0):

In dm-verity, if datablock verification fails, the device generates an I/O error indicating the block cannot be read. It will appear as if the filesystem has been corrupted, as is expected.

There is also one other reason will cause the data corrupted. Accroding to the Android official document, "Specifically, there is a larger probability of unintentional disk corruption, which will cause a verification failure and can potentially make an otherwise functional device unusable if a critical block in the partition can no longer be accessed."

If you want to debug these issues, you can find the corresponding code in the following files:

> 1. user space: ANDROID_SRC/system/core/fs_mgr/fs_mgr_verity.c
> 2. kernel space: KERNEL_SRC/driver/md/dm-verity.c